# LWJGL Wait for key press in a single method

Tags: java, lwjgl, input, gui, keyboard

Currently I am implementing the possibility in my game to change the keyboard configuration.
Therefor, I have a menu in which is a button for each action the player can do. If the player clicks on one of these buttons, the game should wait until the player hits a key on the keyboard.

But this is my problem. I have no idea how to wait for a keypress.
I tried to do something like:

```
while(!Keyboard.next()){}
// Now there should be events. Just get the key of the last event.
```

But it did not work and ended with an infinite loop.
The problem is, it has to work in a single method, as it is the onClick method of the button.

Does somebody know a way to handle this problem correctly?
And how is this done usually? (I have seen such functionality in some games)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm sure you found: `while(!Keyboard.next()){}` would just wait forever, since `Keyboard` is not getting updated during the wait.

In your `OnClick` function, I'd store the action that's being set. Then, when entering your update loop, check to see if you're waiting for an action. If you are, check for a keypress. Something like:

```
//check for cancel (like clicking a separate action)
if(actionToSet != null) {
    if(Keyboard.hasNext()) {
        //check to make sure key pressed is not cancel set action key (like ESC)
        actionToSet.bind(Keyboard.getNext());
    }
}
//do other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MichaelHouse for his suggestion, but what I actually found works (since those methods he suggested didn't appear to exist for the Keyboard class I had), is to set a boolean `waitingToSet` and in my update method, I had this:

```
    if (waitingToSet){
        if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()){
            System.out.println(Keyboard.getKeyName(Keyboard.getEventKey()));
            waitingToSet = false;
        }
    }
```

This worked perfectly for me. Of course you can just then go and bind that `Keyboard.getEventKey()` returned value as the setting you want.

EDIT: Just a caveat: if you're planning on using this with LibGDX, it won't work properly. The Integer values for the `Keyboard` class and the `Input.Keys` field are different, so calling `Gdx.Input.isKeyPressed(i)` where `i` is the int value you caught earlier, will map to the wrong key.
It turned out to be a huge mission for me to get new key mappings to work properly for LibGDX. Ended up using a `Preferences`file and writing my own method that looped through every possible Key and/or button to return the proper one:

```
public static int getKey(){
    for (int i=0;i<256;i++){
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(i)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This worked perfectly. So change the `Keyboard.getEventKeyState()`to `Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.ANY_KEY)` and then call the above method inside the if statement. Then you'll have the right key.